# Preprocessing images in transfer learning (Inception v3)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm using Keras and importing the Inception model that was trained on the 
Imagenet dataset.

`from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3`

I'm importing my images in mini-batches and resizing them, but I am unsure about the correct way to preprocess them.

Do I just take the **mean of each channel** of each batch and subtract each pixel
from their respective channel mean, and then divide by their channel std?

Thank you.